# What is the best way for object detection in an image in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, object-detection, object-detection-api

I need to make object detection in my xamarin project .
so what is the best way to do it , I prefer that it is free ,
if not what is the cost of it please ?

I checked some links and videos and I realized that custom vision api from microsoft azure can make it , but it requires an account on microsoft azure and I have some limitations on the number of transactions ,projects and trainings .
is there is free alternatives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is [object detecting site](https://www.clarifai.com/) in which you can call 5K request per month free.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is a common open source library used for image processing.
[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a c# wrapper that you can use. They provide examples and there are very easy object detection tutorials for OpenCV.